# How do I download videos from screencast-o-matic?

Tags: video, screencasts

After sending a video to a friend, he wants to download the video from the screencast-o-matic.com link. How can he do it? Are there any extensions that support them, or do I need to use another site?

Comment: Do these steps not work? http://feedback.screencast-o-matic.com/knowledgebase/articles/76362-how-can-i-download-a-screencast-that-i-ve-uploaded

Comment: @Folk of course not. that's only for the person who uploaded it, not for my friend, as explained in the question

Answer (score 2):

Don't know any easy way, but I do this to save the video.

- open the link on Google Chrome.
- press (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) this will bring the developer tool.
- select element selection tool (see image)
- click on the video.
- right click on the video tag
- then open the link in new tab
- on the new tab press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the video file.

[image: Save Video from screencast-o-matic.com]